# What's the difference between 合う, 会う, 遭う, 逢う,遇う?

Tags: kanji

I recently stumbled upon the expression 酷{ひど｝い目｛め｝に遭｛あ｝った ("I was having a bad time"), where the verb "to meet" was written using a rather unusual kanji.

After looking into it, I can count at least 5 instances of the verb "あう" meaning "to meet", written using a different kanji:

- 合う
- 会う
- 遭う
- 逢う
- 遇う

What's the difference? As far as I can tell 合う and 会う are the most common ; is there a difference between the two?